# PCRE Regex Match /x... but not /y/x

Tags: regex, pcre

When configuring redirections, it's common to run into multiple pages that include some of the same path strings. We've ran into this instance multiple times where we need to redirect:

```
https://example.com/x...
```

But not:

```
https://example.com/y/x...
```

To match the /x... we use PCRE regex of:

```
/x.*
```

We've been struggling to get the exclude to match correctly; we apologize in advance as our regex is a bit weak, here's our pseudo code:

```
Match all /x... except /y/x...
```

Here is what we thought that looked like:

```
^\/(?!y\/).x.*
```

In our mind that reads:

```
Any query starting with /x..., except starting with /y/x...
```

Thank you in advance, and please feel free to suggest better formatting, we are not stack overflow pros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches from the start of the string a forward slash and then uses a negative lookahead to check what follows is not `y/`. If that is true, then match any character followed by x and 0+ character. That will match for example `//x///`

Without taking matching the url part into account, one way could be to use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` to check if what is on the right side does not contain `/y/x` and then match any character:

`^(?!.*/y/x).+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZnp41/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful starting place. You got exactly the half we are missing, which is exclude /y/x... But that would also match all other queries like /z/. 

Is that intended to append before regex to match /x/? Something like ^(?!.*/y/x).+x.*

Comment: You are brilliant, that worked: ^(?!.*/y/x).*/x.* 

Can you run me through what that reads in pseudo code, so in the future rather than copying this users can learn what they may have misunderstood? 

I see it as all queries that start with excluding all instances of /y/x, except when /x...

Comment: I think you need: ^(?!.*/y/x)/x.+ to match only if it has /x in the path.

Comment: @beta208 That would work `^(?!.*/y/x).*/x.*` if there should be `/x` in the string. It will match until the last occurrence of `/x` and matches any character 0+ times after it.

Comment: Thank you that does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
~(?<!/y)/x~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6nAaL/1)

`(?<!/y)` is a negative lookbehind assertnion that will fail the match if `/y` appears before matching `/x`.

Comment: I do see that this also matches and is shorter. I imagine this is the ideal solution?

Comment: Yes your requirement needed a lookbehind, moreover this one is more efficient than `^(?!.*/y/x).*/x` as you can see in no of steps taken in regex demo link I provided.

Comment: With our system this one did not match /lunch/ but only /lunch. Would it be:    ~(?<!/y)/x.*

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you mean by that. What is your actual regex on your system?